# Simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in React.js

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, react.js

I'm relatively new to react and attempted to create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game. Would be great if i could get some feedback on this. Again, at this point using only React (no Redux).

**main.js** - main file which adds our App component to the DOM

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './container/App';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(App),
    document.getElementById('mount')
  );
});
```

**App.js** - root component that contains the Board and Dashboard. One specific question I had here was: when I receive the `reset()` event from my Dashboard App, what's the best practice on how I can end up triggering the `reset()` of `Board`?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Board from './Board'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            winner: ''
        }
    }

    reset() {
        console.log('how do i pass reset to Board...?')

    }

    hasWinner(winner) {
        this.setState({
            winner: winner
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Board rows={3} cols={3} hasWinner={this.hasWinner.bind(this)} />
                <Dashboard winner={this.state.winner} reset={this.reset.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

**Board.js** - `Board` component that contains `Cell` components! Please ignore the `checkWinner()` method for the purpose of this review.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cell from './Cell'
import styles from '../css/board.css'

export default class Board extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        let board = this.createBoard();

        this.state = {
            board: board,
            currentPlayer: 'X'
        }
    }

    createBoard() {
        let board = new Array(this.props.rows);
        for ( var row = 0 ; row < this.props.rows ; row++ ) {
            board[row] = new Array(this.props.cols);
            board[row].fill('');
        };  

        return board;   
    }

    checkWinner() {
        // TODO: please add correct winner algo!
        return this.state.board[0][0];
    }

    drawBoard() {
        let board = [];
        for ( let i = 0 ; i < this.props.rows ; i++ ) {
            for ( let j = 0 ; j < this.props.cols ; j++ ) {
                var id = i + '' + j;
                board.push(
                    <Cell 
                        key={id}
                        id={id}
                        play={this.play.bind(this)}
                        value={this.state.board[i][j]} />
                );
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    reset() {
        let board = this.createBoard();
        this.setState({
            board: board,
            currentPlayer: 'X'
        })
    }

    play(ij) {
        let i = ij[0];
        let j = ij[1];
        let board = this.state.board;
        board[i][j] = this.state.currentPlayer;
        this.setState({
            board: board,
            currentPlayer: this.state.currentPlayer==='X'?'O':'X'
        })

        let winner = this.checkWinner();
        if ( winner != '' ) {
            this.props.hasWinner(winner);
            this.reset();
        }
    }

    getClassName() {
        return styles.board
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.getClassName()}>
                {this.drawBoard()}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

**Cell.js** - `Cell` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from '../css/cell.css'

export default class Cell extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    getClassName() {
        return styles.emptycell
    }

    play() {
        if ( this.props.value === '' )
            this.props.play(this.props.id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div 
                onClick={this.play.bind(this)} 
                className={this.getClassName()}>
                    {this.props.value}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

**Dashboard.js** - Component to show winner and contains a reset button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Dashboard extends Component {  

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    render() {
        const winner = this.props.winner
                            ?<h1>And the winner is: {this.props.winner}</h1>
                            :<p></p>
        return (
            <div>
                {winner}                    
                <input type="button" value="reset" onClick={this.props.reset} />
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Great job formatting your question - hopefully you get some helpful feedback!

Comment: ^ Thanks and looking forward to some helpful pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options for handling the reset event.

1. If the `Board` component *absolutely must* handle its own logic for setting
   its initial board state, you can add a `ref` prop to it, which allows you
   to hold onto a reference to that instance of the component, and call
   methods on that instance:

   ```
   reset() {
     this.board.reset();
   }
   ...
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <Board rows={3}
                cols={3}
                hasWinner={this.hasWinner.bind(this)}
                ref={(board) => { this.board = board; }} />
         <Dashboard winner={this.state.winner} reset={this.reset.bind(this)} />
       </div>
     )
   }
   ```
2. Your second (and preferred) option is to "[lift up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)" the board state from the
   `Board` component. This is the approach that
   is recommended over using a `ref` in the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).
   Essentially, you want to move your board state and the `createBoard` method from
   the `Board` component to the `App` component.

---

A note on naming:

Your `Board` component's `hasWinner` prop sounds like it should be receiving a
boolean value, rather than a callback. A common convention in React is to prefix
callback props with "on," so your prop names could become `onWin`, `onPlay`, and
`onReset`, for example.

---

Finally, in your `Dashboard` component, instead of rendering an empty `p` tag when there is no winner, you can take advantage of the fact that React skips rendering values like `false` and `null`. So you can replace your ternary statement with something simpler:

```
const winner = this.props.winner && <h1>And the winner is: {this.props.winner}</h1>
```